# Что в php означает знак ->

Tags: php

Что в php означает знак ->

Comment: Благодарю Всех кто откликнулся. Сейчас более менее понятно, но скорее на интуитивном уровне)))

Answer (score 4):

В мануале он называется "object operator" - T_OBJECT_OPERATOR. Используется видимо для вызова нестатических методов класса.

```
Method chaining is read left to right (left associative):
<?php

class Test_Method_Chain
{
    public function One()
    {
        echo "One" . PHP_EOL;
        return $this;
    }

    public function Two()
    {
        echo "Two" . PHP_EOL;
        return $this;
    }

    public function Three()
    {
        echo "Three" . PHP_EOL;
        return $this;
    }
}

$test = new Test_Method_Chain();

$test->One()->Two()->Three();

/* Ouputs:
One
Two
Three
*/
?>
```

Comment: Благодарю)

Comment: Запись $test->One()->Two()->Three() возможна, потому что вызываемые методы возвращают объект того же класса. Где попало подобный вызов работать не будет.
Так же такой вариант использование доступен только с определенной версии php(наверное с 5.3), ранее разыменовывание объекта(получение ссылки на него) в таком виде было недоступно и требовало ввода дополнительной промежуточной переменной.

$a = $test->One();
$b = $a->Two();
$c = $b->Three();

Answer (score 3):

Да. Именно так. Для вызова методов и свойств. В жаве и c# если не ошибаюсь это точка.

Comment: И в javascript

Comment: и в delphi точка, а вот в С++ как и в php ->

Comment: @savro Зря вы так про `C++` :)

Comment: myclass.method() - это C++, не путайте человека. myclass->method() тоже C++, но здесь myclass это указатель, а не объект и не ссылка.

Comment: Небольшой учебный сниппет наглядно иллюстрирующий высказывания предыдущих авторов  о C++

    myclass myclassobject;
    myclass* myclassobjectpointer=&myclassobject;
    myclassobject.method();
    myclassobjectpointer->method();
    myclass::staticmethod();

Comment: Да, уважаемый @Котик. Мне тоже обидно за С++.

Answer (score 1):

Он используется не только для вызова нестатических методов, но и для обращения к свойствам(полям) объекта(а не класса).

Вообще, на сколько я знаю, повелось это из С++.
Вначале был объект. Затем у него появилось свойство и обращаться к нему надо было так объект.свойство. Все бы хорошо, но порой нужно было получать не значение свойства, а указатель на него, так появилась запись объект.*свойство
Данная запись многим показалась некрасивой и ее заменили на объект->свойство.
Т.е. в С++ "->" эквивалентно ".*", ну а в php видимо перекочевал уже конечный вариант.

PS: вот как-то, но возможно я немного ошибаюсь.